# Logo key + up/down arrow keys multitasking shortcut?

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys

On most linux distros I can use the <kbd>Logokey</kbd>+<kbd>Arrowkeys</kbd> to shift the window I'm currently on to one half of the screen.  Only the <kbd>Right arrow</kbd> and <kbd>Left arrow</kbd> keys works for me on Ubuntu.

How can I enable <kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> and <kbd>Down arrow</kbd> keys to split the windows vertically as well?  And also the ability to split the window into one corner (a fourth) of the screen by using the <kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> and <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> arrow keys in sequence.

Comment: Please specify your Ubuntu version and desktop you are using in your question. Use the Edit button to edit your question.

Comment: @grumbo vanadium is right on. Some versions of Ubuntu responde differently to keystroke commands than others do. Please click [edit] and tell us which Ubuntu you use.